# Custom scale from simple list or dict?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to make a custom scale for an axis. Before diving into http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html, I'm wondering if there is an easier way for my special case.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here we go:
[image: The plot I need to improve]

See the value in each row next to the filename ? I would like the row height to be relative to the difference between it and the previous one. I'd start from 0 and would have to define a top limit so I see the last row.

Comment: A code example is worth a thousand pictures ;)

Comment: Not much code to share, I have a numpy array filled with values and use [seaborn.heatmap](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn-dev/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to plot it. Something like `ax = sns.heatmap(hm,xticklabels=round(hm.shape[1]/10),cmap=sns.plt.cm.Reds)` then I add the row names and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [matplotlib's pcolormesh](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) with which you can create irregularly shaped grids.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y1D = np.hstack([0, np.random.random(9)])
y1D = np.sort(y1D)/np.max(y1D)

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1),y1D)

plt.pcolormesh(x,y, np.random.random((10,10)))
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh example]

Comment: This looks like what I need, thanks. Now I need to understand how this works :)

Comment: You give pcolormesh x and y coordinates, which are the coordinates of the corners of each colored block. Then you color the blocks with the final array. The `y1D` and `x` and `y` stuff is what you need to define based on your data (and of course the third argument to pcolormesh, which I now gave random data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recipe and adapt to your needs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grid = np.zeros((20,20))
for i in range(grid.shape[0]):
    r = np.random.randint(1,19)
    grid[i,:r] = np.random.randint(10,30,size=(r,))

plt.imshow(grid,origin='lower',cmap='Reds',interpolation='nearest')
plt.yticks(list(range(20)),['File '+str(i) for i in range(20)])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

, the result is this:

[image]

Comment: This is interesting, I was considering using `imshow` instead of `seaborn.heatmap` for this plot, but is there a simple way to change row heights here ?

Comment: There is with pcolormesh. You give it x and y arrays for the corners of each gridcell and a z array that defines the color values.

Comment: You can either use pcolormesh as suggested or just tinker with aspect ratios and the grid nodes. Matplotlib is very flexible. Imshow also allows size of pixels if I'm not mistaken. Don't have the api present in my mind though.